# What is the appropriate initial value for a ElapsedTime Performance Counter?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter, elapsedtime

What is the proper initial value for an `ElapsedTime` performance counter?  When my app starts up I am setting the `.RawValue` of the performance counter instance to 0 but that is not correct.  It looks like it needs to be based on the current time but I'm not sure what is the actual value I should be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set it to  `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();`

See [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx)